# R - Change return values of existing function

Tags: r, function, functional-programming, statistics

I am using the approxfun() function to get linear interpolation. I want to write a function which takes the results of approxfun() then shifts and scales it by an amount that I specify. I need to be able to call this new function just like I would call any other function.

Simplified version of my attempt:

```
set.seed(42)
x = rnorm(50)
y = rnorm(50, 5, 2)
fhat = approxfun(x, y, rule = 2)

new_function = function(fhat, a, b){

  new_fhat <- (function(fhat, a, b) a * fhat() + b)()

  return(new_fhat)

}
```

I expect the results to be the same as

```
2 * fhat(1) + 3
```

but instead when I run my function

```
new_function(fhat, a = 2, b = 3)
```

I get an error message:

*Error in (function(fhat, a, b) a * fhat() + b)() : 
  argument "a" is missing, with no default*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have four problems:

1. `new_fhat` isn't passed the values of `a` and `b` from the `new_function` call, and can't see them because you are creating new ones in your function definition. This is actually a bit of a red herring because...
2. The function you return should only have a single argument - the point at which you want to evaluate it.
3. You are attempting to evaluate `new_fhat` immediately.
4. You are trying to call `fhat` without an argument.

The solution is:

```
new_function = function(fhat, a, b){

  new_fhat <- function(v) a * fhat(v) + b

  return(new_fhat)

}
```

Results:

```
fhat(1)
[1] 5.31933
new_function(fhat,a=2,b=3)(1)
[1] 13.63866
2 * fhat(1) + 3
[1] 13.63866
```

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to the code in the question, but simplified:

```
new_function = function(fhat, a, b) {
  a * fhat() + b
}
```

But this is not correct, because in the posted code `fhat` requires an argument. For example, to make `new_function(fhat, a = 2, b = 3)` return the same results as `2 * fhat(1) + 3`, you would have to add the parameter 1 inside the function:

```
new_function = function(fhat, a, b) {
  a * fhat(1) + b
}
```